# Can an Inline Visualforce page be hidden by security?

Tags: security, page-layout, inline-visualforce

I'm working on a requirement which speed up my deployment process. 
I have 40 page layouts what I have to update in a production environment. 
Ideally I'd like to add a new inline visual force page to all these 40 page layouts but as a hidden one. Later when all other dependencies are ready I would switch on this page with a security setting.
I went to the Pages --> my inline visualforce page then clicked on the Security.
I removed all of the profiles from the "Enabled Profiles" section but after I'm going back to the Opportunity page layout the inline VF page is still there.

The question is:
Can we hide an inline visualforce page from all 40 page layouts with just one single security setting. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should note that as a developer, you can always see pages, even if they're not enabled for your profile; that's just how it works. That is why when you go back to the detail page, you still see the embedded page. Secondly, turning off the security for all profiles will still cause that page to appear, but the users that are not developers will get a "insufficient priviledges" screen in the area occupied by the page instead of seeing the actual content. So, essentially, the answer is no. I would suggest keeping a copy of the layouts the way you wish them to appear inside a Sandbox so that you can easily deploy all 40 layouts with the click of a button, rather than trying to hide the page in plain sight.

Comment: I have a system administrator profile and because I'm the owner of the object I have no problem that I can see without permission. However my colleagues with Sys Admin profil are also able to see this VF page which is not right I think.

Comment: @tamastom No, that's expected. System administrators are granted additional power over non-admins. Your normal users would be the ones to see the error message.